# Refreshing JS code to display correct data on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using script below to countdown from given time and display how many hours+minutes+seconds left for timeout on the script in real-time.

Counting down woks perfectly fine but the problem I'm facing is, when using **next** and **previous** buttons on browsers, the time doesn't get refreshed and I see old time instead. It either shows previous time or later.

I'm aware that **next** and **previous** buttons on browsers don't refresh pages but how can I overcome this issue?

**JS**

```
function timeout_warning(login_timeout)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var total_seconds = 0;
    var colour = '';
    var interval_id = '';

    interval_id = setInterval(function ()
    {
        counter++;

        total_seconds = login_timeout - counter;
        hours = parseInt(total_seconds / 3600 ) % 24;
        minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60 ) % 60;
        seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60, 10);

        remaining = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);

        if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('font_timeout').innerHTML = 'Timeout';
            window.clearInterval(interval_id);
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('font_timeout').innerHTML = remaining + 'sec';
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**HTML BODY**

```
<body onload="timeout_warning('1800')">
```

Comment: Add a changing hash, and bind to the hashchange event, that usually works for browser back and forward buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Without a live example I can only give an opinion to the solution. You might want to us JavaScript to load the remaining time from a cookie so that when a browser arrow is clicked the code will pull the time from the cookie and not from the cached data.

Answer (score 0):

A [solution has already been posted on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642600/485048) and uses a form to store data in the page to see if the user has pressed the back button. It sets some form data and if the page goes back, it can tell if that data is already set, and if it is, it needs to force a reload (so your timer will start again).