# How do I distinguish an initial page visit from a back navigation in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a web page, `page1.html`, with jQuery scripts on it, including a `$(document)` handler that wires up the event handlers on the page when the page is first visited. After the page is loaded, a user clicks on an `<a>` element and navigates away to another page. The user then back-navigates to the initial `page1.html`.

What I'm seeing is the `$(document)` event handler is firing when the user back-navigates, which was not what I was expecting. I naively assumed that once the page has been "built" by the browser, and the user browses back, the build-up state of the page would still be there.

I would like to be able to distinguish the states "I'm visiting the page afresh" versus "I'm back-navigating to the page after visiting some other page". How is this done, idiomatically, in jQuery?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - you want to fire the event if a user first visits a page and then never fire it for that user? Or you want to fire it every time user enters your page but not when he back-navigates?

Comment: @MythThrazz: the latter. If the user browses "page1.html" then "page2.html", followed by a 'new' "page1.html" visit, I want the event firing twice, but if the user browses "page1.html" then "page2.html" bollowed by a "back navigation", I only want it firing the first time page1.html is visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no truly clean way to do this. Most solutions I've seen for this involve setting cookies using Javascript or hidden form-elements.

There have been a bunch of similar questions on Stackoverflow, you might want to look at this one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642600/677985

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It turns out this is a FAQ -- and that different browsers behave different ways depending on whether someone has installed an unload() event handler or not. Grunt.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTML5 you might get interested in this: http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

Since basically what you have to do is to check if the site's address is in the browser's history, using the `window.history` object (which holds the browser history) may be worth a try.