# How to detect if a user has gone to a page by using the (browser) back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, back

I have some pages with dynamic generated partial views, for example in some search pages.

If a user returned to such pages with the browser back button or with a back button implemented like:

```
@if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
   <button onclick="history.go(-1); return false;" class="flatButtonSecondary">back</button>
}
```

He doesn´t get the dynamic generated inputs loaded from the session or cookies because the page becomes loaded out of the cache of the browser.

I found this similar thread: [How do I detect if a user has got to a page using the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button) 
and implemented the answer like:

```
<form name="ignore_me">
        <input type="text" value="0" id='page_is_dirty' name='page_is_dirty' style="display: none" />
</form>

<script>
   var dirty_bit = $('#page_is_dirty')[0];
   if (dirty_bit.value === '1') window.location.reload();
   function mark_page_dirty() {
      dirty_bit.value = '1';
   }
   $(function () { mark_page_dirty(); })
</script>
```

under the  tag in my layout view so it is called every time I get the page.

So this works fine in Chrome but in Firefox it runs in an endless loop and in IE 10 it just does nothing.

Does anybody have an idea how to run this in all three browsers, or can give me an alternative implementation?

**Edit:**

After some experiments with the different browsers I found a solution that seems to work in all three (FF, IE10, Chrome). Here it is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="page_is_dirty" value="no">
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
        var e = document.getElementById("page_is_dirty");
        if (e.value == "no") e.value = "yes";
        else { e.value = "no"; location.reload(); }
    }
</script>
```

But I´m not sure, why this is running, and my first version is not. Is someone able to fill this gap in my mind?

Comment: There are two other answers in that question. Did you try them?

Comment: No and Yes, i don't try the second beacuase i don#t want to use iframes in my views the third is always false in all browsers so it don't do anythink or i missed something.

Comment: Have you tried `history.length`?

Comment: No, how can i use `history` to check? Can you give me an example? I just checked `history.length` in Chrome and it is always 50.

Comment: Instead of messing around with the back button (which is unreliable) you should simply change the HTTP cache headers of the page in question, so that the browser doesn't cache it.