# :focus is not getting removed if i navigate back

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a child component which has several tabs with the following CSS property:

```
a {
    padding: 7px 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      background-color: pink;
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    }
}
```

When I click on back button it goes back to the previous selected tab which is fine but the focus is not removed from the current one unless I click on any other part of the screen.

How to remove the focus?

Comment: This can't be done with CSS. You could do it with JS though.

Comment: Maybe this answer (jQuery) can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257828/5641669

Comment: @alia Please check my code and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a different solution for that you can set your on navigate back using
`document`  and `id`. Here is a sample code below=>

**HTML:**

```
<input id="abc">
<button (click)="mySetDefaultFocus()">Set Focus</button>
```

**TS:**

```
 mySetDefaultFocus(){
     document.getElementById(`abc`).focus();
  }
```

**Note:** You can call that method `mySetDefaultFocus` on navigate change or `ngInit`.