# Detecting when user hits back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to detect when the user hits the "back" button in their browser.

When clicking on the link and then getting back, nothing happens:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$( window ).on( "navigate", function( event, data ) {
  console.log( data.state );
});
</script>

<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

I was expecting a message in the log.

When the user checks some checkboxes, then go to another page and then returns back, I want to reset the form, so that all checkboxes are empty.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is your intended use for this? An exit offer?

Comment: @hopkins-matt: I want to reset the form: all checkboxes, radio buttons etc.

Comment: You want to clear forms on backwards navigation? Why not just clear them anytime the page loads?

Comment: Will the link that users can click be an internal or external link?

Comment: @hopkins-matt: It will be an external link.

Comment: I've done tracking using cookies to track back navigation before, but that will still only work on internal links. The only think I can see working is resetting on page load.

Comment: If what you want is to clear the form values, how about cleaning the data [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) instead of when the user comes back?

Comment: The question is different but similar in this post. Take a look at the proposed solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button

Comment: @hopkins-matt: Ok, I solved it with `$( window ).load(function() { ... })` now. It didn't work with just `$( document ).ready(function() { ... })`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because your javascript is not running on `google.com`. If you are on the page with your javascript and click the back button, you may see the `console.log` message for a split second, but it is a race between the browser loading previous page and the console loading your message that will determine if you see the message or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The best solution I found was to use a checksum in the initial post. You can then compare the checksum and see if it had been used before, if it was then you can reset everything.