# Trigger a javascript event while closing the Google sign in button

Tags: jquery, google-signin

I have a website with sigle sign in functionality, am using `auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(signInCallback);`
method for google sign in.Is there any javascript event is available to trigger if the user tries to close the login window with out enter his credetials

Comment: Cookies could be a possibility?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button