# How to redirect user to another page once he has clicked the browser back button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect the user to yahoo's page once he has clicked the browser's back button. Here is my attempt, currently nothing happens:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    var lastVisitedUrl = window.history.go(-1);
    window.history.replaceState(lastVisitedUrl , "Sample Title", "/yahoo.com");
    window.location.href.back()
});
```

How can I make the redirection once the browser back button is clicked?

Comment: read this question it might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser

Comment: You can redirect to yahoo ONLY if the previous page is under your control - there should be easily implemented. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button).

Answer (score 0):

Try this works properly

```
window.history.pushState({page: 1}, "", "");

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(event){
        window.location.href = 'https://www.yahoo.com';
       
    }
}
```

Comment: It still returns to the last page, not yahoo

Comment: here you can see where I direct the page `window.location.href = 'https://www.yahoo.com';` when back event is happen

Comment: I thought that it detects the back event and direct the page to yahoo

Comment: It doesn't work on my end. Using Razor pages with .NET 7. After back button is pressed I still get the previous page.