# Disable javascript when going back

Tags: javascript

I'm using a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk), is it possible to disable this script when I go back in the browser?

```
clickme = document.querySelector('[title="Stampa etichette"]');  
if (clickme) {clickme.click()};
```

Thanks very much!

I tried in vain this feature, however deprecated:

```
if (performance.navigation.type != 2){ 
   clickme = document.querySelector('[title="Stampa etichette"]');  
   if (clickme) {clickme.click()};  
}
```

Comment: Save flag into [localStorage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) and check this flag before running

Comment: for reference, `performance.navigation` was deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type ... while now this `PerformanceNavigationTiming.type`  is recommended: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type ... and this answer might interest you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829046/how-do-i-detect-if-a-user-has-got-to-a-page-using-the-back-button

Comment: Thanks, this script didn't work: 
`if (sessionStorage.getItem('scriptEseguito')){ sessionStorage.setItem('scriptEseguito', 
'si'); clickme = document.querySelector('[title="Stampa etichette"]'); if (clickme) 
{clickme.click()}; }`