# Persisting Checkbox state if browser back is clicked after postbacks - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, viewstate

I've a checkbox with autopostback=true. If i check the checkbox the postback occurs and changes a label text. But if i click back in the browser the checkbox is not returning to its previous unchecked state. How can i bring back its state?

Thank you.

## 1

Can i write some JavaScript to persist the state of a control?

NLV

Comment: Doesn't anyone understand my question? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.  The browser does not inform the server of user initiated events, such as the back button.  Therefore, there is no back button event you can code against.

Comment: Can i write any JavaScript fix to persist a control state across the post-back?

Comment: I'm not a JavaScript expert, but I would start by going through the answers to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871/track-when-user-hits-back-button-on-the-browser