# Detect when user goes to website with BACK button on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, browser, event-handling

I'm struggling finding a way to detect if user used BACK button to get to my website either with JavaScript or jQuery.

How can I detect that activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track when user hits back button on the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871/track-when-user-hits-back-button-on-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 History data. "A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes." Then do a JavaScript check on their past history to see if it matches one of your pages, or to see if this is the first page they've visited used, check history.length = 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Store a cookie that shows they were on that page previously. If you're needing to tell if it is not the users first time visiting a page.

Have hidden form data that posts, but the user may be asked to resubmit it when going back to the page (wouldn't recommend).

I don't believe there is a way to access a users browser history outside of your website's scope for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I would like to note, that it doesn't work for me on Mobile, as mobile doesn't refresh the website when you go back

Comment: Does checking the event.persisted value of window.onpageshow(event) function work for you or another method from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979156/mobile-safari-back-button)?

Comment: Yea, I tried these solutions, it doesn't do anything when I click back button on android.